# Lualatex Babel Hebrew working with Article class but not with Beamer

Tags: beamer, luatex, babel, hebrew

This compiles and the Hebrew is visible:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[english]{article}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{SBL Hebrew} % bug in default renderer with dagesh

\begin{document}

word
אֱלֹהִ֗ים
word again

\end{document}
```

This compiles but the Hebrew is not visible:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass[english]{beamer}

\usepackage[bidi=basic]{babel}
\babelfont{rm}{Times New Roman}
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{hebrew}
\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{SBL Hebrew} % bug in default renderer with dagesh

\begin{document}

word
אֱלֹהִ֗ים
word again

\end{document}
```

Any tips that can help me get the beamer code to work? Thanks!

Comment: beamer uses the sans serif (sf) font, so add `\babelfont[hebrew]{sf}[Renderer=Harfbuzz]{SBL Hebrew}`